# FontAwesome circle-o-notch, show on click

Tags: jquery, html, font-awesome

I'm trying to add a spinning circle to a button on click.
Here's the code - https://jsfiddle.net/3upgdxuv/1/

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('i').addClass('fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button CLASS="button">
  <i></i> dada
</button>
```

I don't understand what I'm not doing properly.
Regards

Comment: Is that `button` within a `form`? (Edit: 31piy tells me that it isn't, in the fiddle. The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: If you observe your code using developer tools, it actually adds the classes to the `i` element.

Comment: @31piy: That's the right place to add them.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following 'workaround' does the job:

```
$('.button').on('click', function (){
    $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i>" + " dada"); 
})
```

Thus, you don't need the i-placeholder (or another placeholder):

```
<button class="button">dada</button>
```

You can even get the button text and add it after the i-Element programmatically.

Comment: **Ugh** But why would this be necessary?

Comment: I actually tried all 3 suggestions but still can't get it to work. The spinner is there if I just add it manually. :/

Comment: Have a look at Rory McCrossan's answer. I don't fully promote the solution (because you prepend another spinner at ech click) but he provided an idea why your approach doesn't work

Comment: @warmane: If you wanna try my solution, you have to add the original script-tags.

Comment: @Flocke thanks for that, but I deleted my answer as it seemed to only work as the CDN I reference looked at v4 of FA, not v5. There seems to be something odd going on with the latest version. I'll investigate when I have more time.

Comment: All 3 work on the jsfiddle but doesn't work in the original code. I thought that my jsfiddle was the same as the original code as it was not working properly, I guess not.

Comment: Thank you everybody, seeing as some of you are bamboozled makes me feel so much better about my lack of ideas.